# Why does slicing in python stop at -1?

Tags: python, slice

`"abcde"[0:5:1]` gives abcde. So I expected `"abcde"[4:-1:-1]` to return edcba but it gives nothing.
Is there no way to get same result as `"abcde"[4::-1]` while explicitly giving middle parameter?

Comment: Middle section of ```slice``` expression is like this: ```len(obj)-1```. In your case ```abcde[4:4:-1]```.

Comment: Maybe you want something like this: `"abcde"[4:None:-1]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-1` in slicing in Python means: the 4rth (last before last).
`4:-1` means then `4:4` -> empty string.

```
"abcde"[4::-1] # this gives "edcba"
"abcde"[4:-(len("abcde")+1):-1] # this too
```

Answer (score 1):

0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4

a | b | c | d | e

=============

[4:-1:-1]

```
 4  -> e

-1 -> e

-1 -> step back
```

=============

=> nothing between index 4 -> -1 with a step back

Answer (score 0):

You are slicing from the last index (4) to index 4 which results in an empty string. In other words, Python is doing the following:

```
"abcde"[4:4:-1]
# which is equal to
"abcde"[4:4]
# and evaluates to
""
```

If you slice from the last index (4) to the first index (0) with a stride of -1 you can reverse it. Thus the following code would work:

```
"abcde"[-1:0:-1]
```

Which in actual practice can be abbreviated to:

```
"abcde"[::-1]
```

Comment: Specifically, `"abcde"[0:-1:-1`] should be `"abcde"[-1:0:-1]`, which still doesn't work (since it omits "a" by stoppingat index 1 not 0). `"abcde"[-1::-1]` works fine though, since an empty start or end means "the start or end that makes sense in the context of the stride sign"

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use a number for the *stop* position, for example, you are using a variable to represent the *stop* index, then you can use the negative value equal to `-len(obj) - 1` where `obj` is the object you want to reverse as the position before the first character:

```
>>> 'abcde'[4:-6:-1]
'edcba'
```

or,

```
>>> 'abcde'[-1:-6:-1]
'edcba'
```

Answer (score 0):

Python list syntax is:

> list[start:stop:step]

In the first example: start=0, stop=5, step=1. This is equivalent to the C style for loop:

> for (i=0; i<5; i++)

In your second example, start=4, stop=-1=4, step = -1. This is equivalent to the C style for loop:

> for (i=4; i>4; i--)

Since the start and stop conditions are the same, your result is empty.

Since -1 is a negative number, which as a start/stop is a special case in python list slicing that means "len(list)-1", you can't actually do the operation you want:

> for (i=4; i>-1; i--)

So instead your best bet is "abcde"[::-1] which will correctly infer the end, and the start, from the direction.